# JCombobox and String.equals(null)

Tags: java, string, null, equals, jcombobox

Here is my code :

```
if (ChoixPortCom.equals(null) == true ) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choose Port COM");
```

and I get the famous     java.lang.NullPointerException

My JCombobox is filled like :
    1st -> nothin/empty null no String nothing
    2nd -> COM1
    3nd -> COM2
    ....

Why is "if" condition not right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`choixPortCom.equals(null)` will never be true. If `choixPortCom` is not `null`, then the expression will return false as expected. If `choixPortCom` *is* `null`, then the expression will throw a `NullPointerException`, since you are attempting to call a method on `null`; this is what's happening in your case. The appropriate way to check for `null` is:

```
if (choixPortCom == null)  // I've assumed a more common naming convention
```

There is also an `Objects` class in Java 7 that has some useful methods for `null`-checking. For example, [`Objects.requireNonNull()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull%28T,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
Objects.requireNonNull(choixPortCom, "input can't be null!")
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
if (ChoixPortCom == null)
```

Now if ChoixPortCom is null it will throw a NullPointer because you are trying to invoke a method (equals) on a null reference.

And something I like to think of as a best practice is to always use brackets:

```
if (ChoixPortCom == null) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Choose Port COM");
}
```

Comment: Can you do this if ChoixPortCom is a String ?

Comment: Definitely. String is also an object.

Comment: yep you were right, it works. I did with String.equals() because we told me to this when I compare with a String. Never mind, thanks.

Comment: And please follow java code conventions , variables names starts with lower-case and follow a camel-case style

Comment: The comparison would then be with a String value such as stringObject.equals("D3fman"); Even better: "D3fman".equals(stringObject); (now if stringObject == null you don't get a nullpointer)